# Can I get tensorflow-gpu to work with NVIDIA GeForce MX130?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, gpu

I understand this is not a recommended setup for machine learning in any sense, but I would like to work with what I have.

Not being an expert, I have been told that tf-gpu should work with any device supported by cuda.

When I run:

```
from numba import cuda
cuda.detect()
```

I get:

```
Found 1 CUDA devices
id 0        b'GeForce MX130'                              [SUPPORTED]
                      compute capability: 5.0
                           pci device id: 0
                              pci bus id: 1
Summary:
    1/1 devices are supported
```

And I can get the GPU to work with some basic 'vectorized' tasks.

Also, running:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
```

will return True

However, running

```
tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('gpu')
```

will return an empty list.

Running:

```
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

Will return:

```
Num GPUs Available:  0
```

Running:

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
print("Number of devices: {}".format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))
```

will return:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:There are non-GPU devices in `tf.distribute.Strategy`, not using nccl allreduce.
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',)
Number of devices: 1
```

I have trained some basic models with the non-gpu version of tensorflow but I have no clue about how to deal with tf-gpu. I was able to fit a model with CuDNNLSTM layers, but the script didn't use the GPU, according to task manager.

I will appreciate any advice on how to get it to use my 'gpu' or a confirmation that it is not possible. Thanks!

EDITED:

I uninstalled keras and both tensorflow versions and installed only tensorflow-gpu. Nothing changed.

Comment: Could you use the NVIDIA GeForce MX130 for Tensorflow? I have the same running windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately No.

Even though the official specs stated 'Yes', the CUDA GPU list did not mentioned MX130 as part of its list.

(I also running MX130 on my notebook)

reference:

- official specs: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/gaming-laptops/mx130/specifications/
- CUDA enabled GPU list: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Comment: I flagued this as the correct answer because I tried the solutions suggested by others and none of it worked.

Comment: The answer is not true. Review your enviroment path variable if you are using Windows.  In my system it is pointing to...

C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\libnvvp;
C:\Apps\CUDNN8.1\bin;

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely YES!

I assume that the compute capability: 5.0 is enough.

I tested my Geforce MX130 with tensorflow-gpu installed by conda (which handles the cuda, versions compatibility, etc.) in Python 3.7

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

That's it! no more actions were required.
The following versions were installed:

```
tensorflow-gpu: 2.1.0
cudatoolkit: 10.1.243
cudnn: 7.6.5
```

... and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Install Cuda and CuDNN both. Set the paths for them. For checking if TensorFlow is  using GPU, use this:

`sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))`

It should show your GPU name in its output.

Comment: thanks for your answer, this function didn't work with my version of tf  (2.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can...tensorflow-gpu 2.5.0 + CUDA 11.2 + CUDNN 8.1

[image: Tensorflow Output]

[image: GPU use]

[image: Training a model]

Review your enviroment path variable if you are using Windows. In my system it is pointing to...

C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin;

C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\libnvvp;

C:\Apps\CUDNN8.1\bin;